# How can I get a packagemanager object if i am not extending the activity class in Android/ Java?

Tags: android, object, android-activity

i am trying to set up a helper class that does not extend the Activity class. How ever i need to get a packagemanager object with `getPackageManager()`. How can i do this?

Why I am needing this? Well i am trying to setup this Helper class and I tried doing it with my Helper class that extended `Activity`. However I always got a nullpointerexceptions since my helper object was null.

Any tips?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: You probably are going to instantiate this Helper class inside an activity context, so why not pass the `getPackageManager()` return to the Helper constructor or even current activity's `this`?

Comment: @Voicu It's probably an idea to pass the Context as opposed to the return because it's likely it'll be needed again apart from this scenario

Comment: @Zackehh9lives: I agree. And have a class field of type Context that gets initialized in the constructor, so you can use it in other methods of the Helper class.

Comment: @Voicu thanks! it worked great with `this`. But what are you guys meaning by this idea of passing the Context??

Comment: @user2426316 I added an answer to demonstrate what we mean :)

Comment: @Zackehh9lives great!

Comment: @user2426316 Did you get it working? If so you might want to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the best way to do what you're trying to do it pass the `Context` to the constructor of your new class. That way you can then use that to call methods which belong to the `Activity`.

An example is below, it should help you work out your problem:

```
private Context context;

// ...

public HelperClass(Context c){
    context = c;
}

// ...

context.getPackageManager();
```

You can then call it by just adding your Context when you initialize the new class:

```
new HelperClass(this);
```

Although in certain situations, such as from a Fragment, you may have to provide `getActivity();`.

```
new HelperClass(getActivity());
```

Try edit your class as shown above and let us know if you see any improvements.

As mentioned in the comments, unless you're planning on using your context to edits views etc. you'd be better off with `context = c.getApplicationContext();` in your constructor.

Comment: Please note that unless you REALLY, REALLY need an Activity context (e.g., you'll be creating Views from it and you need to apply a theme), you should do `context = c.getApplicationContext()` in HelperClass.

Comment: Be careful when maintaining a reference to a `Context` in helper classes - it can be a cause of memory leaks.